# CSS is not being aplied, maybe due to character's not being escaped?

Tags: html, css, escaping, html-table

I need to clarify: I've been stuck on this for an hour now because I'm not sure what the issue is. I pasted a full example which breaks on jsbin.com as well.

[JSBIN LINK](https://jsbin.com/quwateduka/edit?html,css,output)

#### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="darkstyle" style="width: 15%;">
                <div>URI</div>
            </td>
            <td class="lightstyle" style="width: 85%;">someurl</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="darkstyle" style="width: 15%;">
                <div>Confidence</div>
            </td>
            <td class="lightstyle" style="width: 85%;">Low</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="darkstyle" style="width: 15%;">
                <div>Attack</div>
            </td>
            <td class="lightstyle" style="width: 85%;">Cookies set from a subdomain like app.foo.bar are transmitted only to that domain by the browser. However, cookies scoped to a parent-level domain may be transmitted to the parent, or any subdomain of the parent.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="darkstyle" style="width: 15%; word-wrap: break-word;">
                <div>OtherInfo</div>
            </td>
            <td class="lightstyle" style="width: 85%;">
                <div>aaaThe origin domain used for comparison was: &#13;
myurl.ca&#13;
DERPCOOKIE=&amp;quot;&amp;quot;&#13;
COOKIE3=ASDASD-97867867848-uPKyGldjZwWptQWPkC2wgZ0yW5cCx9ePuVoJjVxyJlrsV1BRT5&#13;
MORECOOKIE_GOODIES=N98R4398R7Y3BF78645389M4D4M37645D348RSJM3645SDN83TY74SWM457R35MYRS3M4875UR3,S4MR34MYRS834JRYMS3784R3487R3M4RM378R34RM,3&#13;
MORECOOKIE_GOODIESB=894FH34897RFH32948FJ3489RFH3478FGH3289RH234F68Y3GH7948RFH3DFC8734HRF938FH39408RJ394FHJ349FH34&#13;
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :**

#### CSS

```
.lightstylediv{
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.lightstyle{
  vertical-align: text-top; 
  background:#b3b3b3;
}
```

`darkstyle` is the same thing, just different color.

If you remove everything in the div containing `<div>aaaThe or` Then it works fine.

The `&amp;quot;&amp;quot;` is being displayed as `&quot` instead of ", how do I fix this?

`&#13;` is just carriage return so shouldn't affect it poorly.

The strings are very long however and they could be the reason it's breaking the table `width`?

Comment: you mean your CSS percentages (inline)? because the classes arent in the code that you have pasted on here.

Comment: We need to see the CSS to be able to help you.

Comment: @freestock.tk The classes lightstyle and darkstyle just change color and fonts. They work fine. width you see there is to change the column size. The first column i to take 15% while the 2nd column takes the remaining 85%.

Comment: Please refine your question.  Your sample includes partial tables.  Can you reproduce it at http://jsbin.com

Comment: @Adam Youngers I updated with sample code that breaks on jsbin.com. Stuck for an hour now, not completely sure breaking it, the escape chars, the random junk or the long word which is cookie data.

Comment: Not seeing a link to the jsbin.

Comment: @Adam Youngers - https://jsbin.com/quwateduka/edit?html,css,output

Comment: The unbroken string is what is causing it.   You either need to truncate it or force a space in the string via JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple,

- you need to set `table-layout:fixed` to `table`
- you were applying `break-word` on the wrong `td`
- avoid using inline styles
- I'm gonna guess and think you are after `vertical-align:top` instead of `text-top`

#### Snippet

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%
}
.darkstyle {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 15%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.lightstyle {
  background: #b3b3b3;
  width: 85%;
  word-wrap: break-word
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="darkstyle">
      URI
    </td>
    <td class="lightstyle">someurl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="darkstyle">
      Confidence
    </td>
    <td class="lightstyle">Low</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="darkstyle">
      Attack
    </td>
    <td class="lightstyle">Cookies set from a subdomain like app.foo.bar are transmitted only to that domain by the browser. However, cookies scoped to a parent-level domain may be transmitted to the parent, or any subdomain of the parent.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="darkstyle">
      OtherInfo
    </td>
    <td class="lightstyle">
      The origin domain used for comparison was: &#13; myurl.ca&#13; DERPCOOKIE=&amp;quot;&amp;quot;&#13; COOKIE3=ASDASD-97867867848-uPKyGldjZwWptQWPkC2wgZ0yW5cCx9ePuVoJjVxyJlrsV1BRT5&#13; MORECOOKIE_GOODIES=N98R4398R7Y3BF78645389M4D4M37645D348RSJM3645SDN83TY74SWM457R35MYRS3M4875UR3,S4MR34MYRS834JRYMS3784R3487R3M4RM378R34RM,3&#13;
      MORECOOKIE_GOODIESB=894FH34897RFH32948FJ3489RFH3478FGH3289RH234F68Y3GH7948RFH3DFC8734HRF938FH39408RJ394FHJ349FH34&#13;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is great! Thank you sir :) One last question. Any idea why the `&quot;&quot` didn't get turned into 2x `"`?

Comment: Your output is returning &amp;quot;&amp;quot;  not  &quot;&quot;

Comment: @AdamYoungers Exactly, that means it wont return `""`

Comment: @codeCompiler77 if this solves your issue please make sure you mark the answer as accepted for future readers know too

Comment: @dippas it was two issues related. So it there no way for me to fix `"` with an html tag or something? If there isn't i can mark it as answered :) Thank you!

Comment: hard to understand what you are trying to say. explain better.

Comment: @dippas is there any way to `&amp;quot;&amp;quot;` render this properly from the html side? or would i need to modify the original source file before generating the html?

Comment: it needs to be render like `&quot;&quot;` in order to show `""`, so you have to remove the `&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to truncate the text and show the full copy on hover via a tooltip.  Here is an option done via css...

http://jsbin.com/koheja/edit?html,css,js,output

```
.ellipsis {
  cursor: help;
  display:block;
  width:250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #f00;

}
```

And update the html as...

```
         <td class="lightstyle" style="width: 85%;">
                  <abbr class="ellipsis" title="aaaThe origin domain used for comparison was: &#13;
    myurl.ca&#13;
    DERPCOOKIE=&amp;quot;&amp;quot;&#13;
    COOKIE3=ASDASD-97867867848-uPKyGldjZwWptQWPkC2wgZ0yW5cCx9ePuVoJjVxyJlrsV1BRT5&#13;
    MORECOOKIE_GOODIES=N98R4398R7Y3BF78645389M4D4M37645D348RSJM3645SDN83TY74SWM457R35MYRS3M4875UR3,S4MR34MYRS834JRYMS3784R3487R3M4RM378R34RM,3&#13; MORECOOKIE_GOODIESB=894FH34897RFH32948FJ3489RFH3478FGH3289RH234F68Y3GH7948RFH3DFC8734HRF938FH39408RJ394FHJ349FH34&#13;">
aaaThe origin domain used for comparison was: &#13;
    myurl.ca&#13;
    DERPCOOKIE=&amp;quot;&amp;quot;&#13;
    COOKIE3=ASDASD-97867867848-uPKyGldjZwWptQWPkC2wgZ0yW5cCx9ePuVoJjVxyJlrsV1BRT5&#13;
    MORECOOKIE_GOODIES=N98R4398R7Y3BF78645389M4D4M37645D348RSJM3645SDN83TY74SWM457R35MYRS3M4875UR3,S4MR34MYRS834JRYMS3784R3487R3M4RM378R34RM,3&#13;
    MORECOOKIE_GOODIESB=894FH34897RFH32948FJ3489RFH3478FGH3289RH234F68Y3GH7948RFH3DFC8734HRF938FH39408RJ394FHJ349FH34&#13;
                    </abbr>
                </td>
```

Comment: @Adan Youngers No Java Script or hovers for this one :( It's part of a larger report i'm working on so it has to be there. I just don't understand why the overflow break isn't working when i try it. Thanks for the help :)