# Table css width is broken by colspan attribute

Tags: html, css

When you create a table with

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

and it consumes 100% width. Then you try to create 4 columns (10%, 10%, 40%, 40%)

However, some rows are only 2 columns long so we use `colspan="2"`, this however breaks the predefined width value and distributes everything evenly.

My current solution is to have nested tables in `td` tags.

Is there a better way to do this or stop the `colspan` from breaking my width?

A simple 2 column example that breaks is below:

EDIT: **CODE** Updated the code for a better example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
  table {
    table-layout: fixed;
   }
  </style>    
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
  <caption>Table of Contents</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>1</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 95%;" colspan="2">
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>a)</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Section Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>a)</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Section Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>2</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>-</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>3</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>-</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED WITH SOLUTION**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>  
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="short" />
    <col class="short" />
    <col class="long" />
  </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <div>Table of Contents</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>1</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 95%;" colspan="2">
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>a)</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Section Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>a)</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Section Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>2</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>-</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>3</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>-</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.short {
  width: 5%;
}
.long {
  width: 90%;  
}
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.short {
  width: 5%;
}
.long {
  width: 90%;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>  
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="short" />
    <col class="short" />
    <col class="long" />
  </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <div>Table of Contents</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>1</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 95%;" colspan="2">
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>a)</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Section Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>a)</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Section Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>2</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>-</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90%;">
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>3</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>-</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Chapter Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `colgroup` ([original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17832737/4861854))

```css
html * {
  font-size: 98%;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Arial !important;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.short {
  width: 5%;
}

.long {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="short" />
    <col class="long" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div style="font-size: 300%;">Table of Contents</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [caption tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption)?

The caption element is semantically defined as the title for a table (which is what you are trying to do) and has been available since at least [HTML 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html#table). It is compatible with all browser versions, including IE6. You can style it with CSS to achieve the look & feel you're after.

```css
html *
{
  font-size: 98%;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Arial !important;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 300%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <caption>Table of Contents</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%;">
        <div>1</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 95%;">
        <div>Name</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yes i had, please see update above. Table of Content has Chapters and then Sections and Sub Sections. I was using `colspan` for formatting.

Comment: Thank you for the help mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't simply specify `table { width: 100%; }` instead of using `table-layout: fixed;` ?

```
html *
{
   font-size: 98%;
   color: #000;
   font-family: Arial !important;
}
table {
   width:100%;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    word-break: break-all;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L05v6s8z/

Comment: Overflow from long words breaks the scaling and word-break alone doesn't fix it. The layout has to be fixed :( Comes from this issue [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713128/css-is-not-being-aplied-maybe-due-to-characters-not-being-escaped)